# GAM with MRF smoother: create neighbourhood structure with duplicate coordinates

Tags: r, mgcv, spdep

I want to use the `mgcv` package in R to run the model

```
df <- as.data.frame(spdf)
mod <- gam(y ~ s(geoid, bs = 'mrf', xt = list(nb = nb), k = 20) +     
               s(month, bs = 'cc', k = 12),
                data = df,
                method = 'REML',
                family = Gamma(link = log))
```

where spdf is a SpatialPolygonDataFrame.

I am having problems understanding how to create the `nb` object since the data `df` have duplicates `geoid` values (one for each month) and when I run

```
nb <- poly2nb(spdf, row.names = spdf@data@geoid)
```

I get the error

```
Error in poly2nb(spdf, row.names = spdf@data@geoid): non-unique row.names given
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neighbourhood object doesn't need to have as many rows as the data, just as many rows as there are `geoid`s.

If you are going to use `geoid` from the data, you'll want to subset the object first to contain non-duplicated `geoid` values. Using the typical subsetting methods (`[`) and `duplicated()` on the `@data` element of the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` should get you a unique set of `geoid`s to build the neighbourhood object from.